# Node at a longest distance from another node in a tree

Tags: c++, algorithm, tree

Given a input a tree we need to answer the queries of the type,

`a)` given a node of the above tree, which is the node which is at the longest distance from that node.

`b)` remove a particular set of edges from the tree.

I have been trying this for a long time but the best solution I could come up with was,

For a query of type `a` call `dfs` function which would return the farthest node in `O(N)`, but i need to do better. 
For a query of type `b`, just update the tree [remove edge if exists].

So my solution above is roughly `O(K*N)` where `K` is the number of queries and `N` is the number of Nodes.

Comment: what is the limit for K and the limit for N?

Comment: both can go upto 100000.

Comment: And what happens if you remove a set of edges? The tree will become disconnected for sure so there may be unreachable nodes from the current node

Comment: Yes, so we have to output the node which is at the largest distance[within that connected component], if there is only one node left, that particular node would be the answer.

Comment: Are the queries known beforehand? (e.g. if this is a competition problem)

Comment: Yes, we know the queries.

Comment: This sounds like a union-find problem. Try arbitrarily picking a root and then finding the deepest nodes in the left/right subtree. That'll give you O(log N) runtime for queries if the tree is balanced.

Answer (score 1):

Since your tree is a general tree, i.e., it has no notion of being balanced or even having a root, the best you can do for a one-off query is `O(n)`. However, I think you can set up the tree once taking `O(n)` time and then have each following query take constant time.

The idea is to find the "middle" of the tree which separate the tree into to roughly equal sized trees, calling the parts arbitrary, e.g., *left* and *right*. You then label all nodes in their respective parts with the part they are in and store a left and a right node which are farthest away from the middle. When you get a query for a node you just look at the node's label and report the stored node on the other side.

Given the comment [and the unwarranted downvote] it seems the solution requires a bit more explanation. First off, the furthest apart node for a given node is, in general, not unique. Imagine for example a path with exactly three nodes. There are two furthest away nodes for the middle node. Either one of them is a solution. Based on that, the idea is to find a node in the tree which is located in the middle of the path between the two farthest apart nodes in the tree (of the distance between these nodes is odd, a node on either side can be chosen such that the distances differ by just one): If the farthest apart nodes are *l* nodes apart, the middle node has a path of length *l/2* to both of them or a path of *l/2* to one and *l/2+1* to the other.

Using this middle node to separate the tree into two halves, randomly called the *left* and the *right* half, makes it possible to determine the farthest apart node for any given node if each node knows whether it is in the left or the right half: the longest path will go through the middle node into the other half and from there to the node farthest away from the middle. Let's call the length of the longest path in the left part *ll* and the length of the longest path in the right part *lr*. Without loss of generality, have *lr < ll* (just swap the names around). The respective farthest apart nodes from the middle are called *nl* and *nr*. Note that it is OK if there are multiple subtrees leading from the middle node which are considered part of the right part as long as one of the longest path (or the longest path if it is unique) is in the left part.

There are three cases to consider when you want to state the furthest apart node from a node *n*:

1. The node *n* is the middle node. In this case, the furthest apart node is clearly *nl*.
2. The node *n* is in the right part of the tree. The longest path you can construct travels to the middle and then to *nl*, i.e., the furthest apart node is clearly *nl*, too
3. The node *n* is in the left part of the tree. Again, the longest path you can construct travels to the middle but from there to *nr*.

The only question remaining is how to find the middle node in `O(n)` time:

1. Find all leaf nodes and put them into a queue, labeling them with `1` and giving them a distance of `0`. This can be done in `O(n)` time [and space].
2. Read (but don't extra, yet) the first node from the queue and find all adjacent nodes. If there is a node with a label which is less than its number of adjacent nodes, increment the label. If the label now matches the number of adjacent nodes, add the node to the queue and give it a distance one bigger than the first node from the queue.
3. If there is only one node in the queue, this node is the middle node and this step terminates.
4. Otherwise, extract the front node and continue processing the queue (i.e., step 2).

As a final pass, find the adjacent node with the biggest distance label and consider the tree hanging off this node the left tree. While labeling the nodes as left nodes with a BFS keep track of the last node in the queue to find *nl*. Consider all other subtrees right trees and label them with BFS, too, as right nodes, also finding *nr*.

I guess, the preprocessing of the tree can be done more elegantly, possibly using few passes, too, but I'm sure the above approach does work.

Comment: Splitting the tree arbitrary can in no way help finding the furthest node.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev: Correct. Note, however, that I didn't suggest to split it _arbitrarily_! Instead, I stated to split it in the _middle_ which isn't that easy to find but it isn't that hard, either, and can certainly be done in `O(n)`. Admittedly, I didn't spell out exactly what I meant with middle (a node which lies on the middle between the two furthest apart nodes in the tree).

Comment: I believe what you mean is called `center` and it lies in the middle of a diameter of the tree. Still the `center` will not help you find the node furthest from any node in the tree.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev: I can believe that it is called the center but it _does_ help to find the furthest away node as any path to the furthest away node will pass through the center or start with the center. You'll label nodes in the subtree from the center to the node furthest away from the center with one indicator (I used _left_ in the above description but this may be deceptive and _green_ would have been better). If there are multiple subtrees with this properties you just choose one of them.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev: ...  All other non-center nodes are labeled differently (I called it _right_ but probably _red_ would have been better). A longest path from a node will go through the center to furthest away node on the other side.

Comment: Uncasting the downvote. Just a tip: to find the center of a tree - run a BFS from any node and find the node furthest from it. After that run BFS from that node and it will form diameter with the node that is furthest away from it. The center is in the middle of the diameter. I still am not sure your solution will be able to maintain the structure as you remove edges by the way.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjey: The algorithm I described doesn't change the tree structure. It merely records information with each mode (number of visited adjacent nodes, distance from a leaf, and the color). If course, once the colors are found the structure isn't needed aymore.

Comment: I mean the b) type requests in the question